STOMP WebSocket using Spring message lost
@EventListener
public void handleWebSocketSubscribeListener(SessionSubscribeEvent event) {

    StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(event.getMessage());

    final Long chattingRoomId = Long.valueOf(headerAccessor.getSubscriptionId());
    final String loginId = headerAccessor.getUser().getName();

    chattingRoomConnectService.connectChattingRoom(chattingRoomId,loginId,headerAccessor.getSessionId());
    chattingService.sendEnterMessage(chattingRoomId,loginId);
    chattingService.updateCountAllZero(chattingRoomId,loginId);

    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put(SUB,chattingRoomId);
}

I want to send the "Enter Message" to subscribed Chatting Room after Subscribe, but the code above seems to send a message merely based on the client's request even before the subscription is actually completed rather than after the subscription has been established.
I considered using @SubscribeMapping along with a return, but the message was only sent to the client that made the subscription request.
I just need something like SubscribedEvent.
Can you give me some advice?

The @SubscribeMapping annotation by default sends the return value to the user. However, by using annotations such as @SendTo or utilizing SimpMessagingTemplate, you can directly specify the topic endpoint where the message should be sent.
You could write the Controller class like this:
private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

...

@SubscribeMapping("/chat/{chattingRoomId}")
@SendTo("/topic/chat/{chattingRoomId}")
public void handleSubscription(@DestinationVariable Long chattingRoomId, StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    String loginId = headerAccessor.getUser().getName();

    return loginId + " has entered the room!";
}

Or like this:
private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

...

@SubscribeMapping("/chat/{chattingRoomId}")
public void handleSubscription(@DestinationVariable Long chattingRoomId, StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
    String loginId = headerAccessor.getUser().getName();

    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/chat/" + chattingRoomId, loginId + " has entered the room!");
}

